# Extract texts until certain patterns on Scrapy

Tags: regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape certain contents from a webpage using Scrapy.

The html element looks like below.

```
'<p>\n                                    阪急宝塚線\xa0/\xa0石橋駅\xa0徒歩1分\n                                                                            （<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="cursor:pointer;" onclic
k=\'window.open("http://athome.ekiworld.net/?id=athome&amp;to=ａｓｓｏ ３０２ ワンルーム&amp;to_near_station1=25824&amp;to_near_time1=1&amp;to_near_traffic1=徒歩 1 分");return false;\'>電車ルート案内</a>）\n
                                                </p>'
```

My goal is to extract only this part "阪急宝塚線\xa0/\xa0石橋駅\xa0徒歩1分\n". 
I tried to use `.re()` with response and I thought `^(.+?<a)` would work since it succeeded parsing on https://regex101.com/. But on scrapy shell, it doesn't parse anything (gives me []).

Could someone help me with this? 
I use Python3/scrapy1.3.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

text =  '''<p>\n                                    阪急宝塚線\xa0/\xa0石橋駅\xa0徒歩1分\n                                                                            （<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="cursor:pointer;" onclic
k=\'window.open("http://athome.ekiworld.net/?id=athome&amp;to=ａｓｓｏ ３０２ ワンルーム&amp;to_near_station1=25824&amp;to_near_time1=1&amp;to_near_traffic1=徒歩 1 分");return false;\'>電車ルート案内</a>）\n
                                                </p>'''

re.search(r'\n.+?\n', text).group()
```

out:

```
'\n                                    阪急宝塚線\xa0/\xa0石橋駅\xa0徒歩1分\n'
```